# I want to develop my project related to Cardano

Tags: wallet, cardano-node, transaction, blockfrost, transaction-history

I want to develop a personal project related to Cardano. I have read some documents, but they require using `project_id` from `Blockfrost`. However, I don’t want to go that route. So, I’m wondering where to start. Are there any libraries or APIs that support this? I’m using Node.js and want to perform functions such as `creating wallets`, `checking balances`, `transferring`, etc.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what route you are refering? You need an API (such as Blockfrost) to access to the data on the Cardano network. Are you looking to run and index your own node?

Comment: My point is like this: Ethereum, I can use web3js to directly interact with the network and perform the mentioned functions. However, if I use Blockfrost to interact with Cardano, I need a project_id. So, I'm looking for a solution that allows free access to the Cardano network.

Comment: Even with web3js, you need a provider of the data, same as in Cardano.

In Ethereum, you can use Infura, in Cardano, you can use for example Blockfrost. In both you can use your own local node (altought in Eth it is much easier to setup).

Comment: An alternative to Blockfrost is the https://koios.rest API